# Jquery each and visible - Unknown Pseudoclass or Pseudoelement 'visible'

Tags: jquery, each, visible

i have a problem with jquery/visible. Hope somebody can help me.

This code works, but i get an error in firebug

```
$('.fse:visible').each(function (i)
```

**-> Unknown Pseudoclass or Pseudoelement 'visible'.**

second try

```
$('.fse').is(':visible').each(function (i)
```

**->  $(".fse").is(":visible").each is not a function**

Whats wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is an **Error** but a **CSS Warning** you are getting and it is normal. Had the same trouble (even appears on the jquery.com website) some time back.

See the discussion here:
http://old.nabble.com/Unknown-pseudo-class-or-pseudo-element-%27odd%27.-td25425663s27240.html

Answer (score 2):

$('.fse').is(':visible') checks if the element is visible or not and returns true or false. Appending ".each" is the same as you would typing "false.each(...)" or "true.each(...)". And "true" or "false" does not have a method called "each".

You can try it using the find-selector: $.find('.fse:visible').each(...) or jQuery.find('.fse.visible').

Answer (score 2):

Though an old article i couldn't find the way i handle it as an solutions. And for me it works fine. So here it is:

```
$('.fse').filter(':visible').each( function () {
    //do something here
});
```

Hope i could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is a bit mysterious, based on the information you have provided. The second makes perfect sense since `.is(":visible")` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you also have Prototype (or another library using `$`) included in the page, is that the case?

Try `jQuery('.fse:visible').each(function (i) {...` to verify that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since class can commonly defined u cant use as $(".classname : visible").each(function(i))

try this:

if($('.fse').is(':visible'))
{
//Do something here
$(this).css({'color':'red'});
}